# Kubernetes Cluster: ""A dependency job for kubelet.service failed""

Tags: kubernetes

I just want to know if any of you guys have ever followed this tutorial before and successed.
I don't know why but whenever i restart and enable services on MINION side, it always failed with error "A Dependency job for kubelet.service failed" and of course it led to kubelet.service started failed.
It didn't work no matter how many times i tried.
So anyone has any idea?

http://severalnines.com/blog/installing-kubernetes-cluster-minions-centos7-manage-pods-services

Answer (score 2):

Most probably docker service failed to start. It's the only dependency to kubelet service.

Comment: Just kubelet.service on minion-side failed, i don't know why. And what's the dependency of kubelet.service? How to fix it? Because kubelet.service couldn't start so i couldn't establish a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Check systemctl status docker -l

Comment: I remembered that when i was using that command to check status of docker, it said: unactive. Even though i couldn't start it with this command:
systemctl start docker.service
.It always failed..
Anyway, i will try to install from the scratch one more time to see the output of this command.

Comment: This is the output, just as i thought it was INACTIVE. But everytime i start it, it will freeze and i couldn't do anything.

 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           mqflannel.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-02-01 07:07:04 UTC; 22s ago

Comment: If not freezing, one error appeared like this:

Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited wit                    . See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for det

Comment: Can you put in your post the entire output from systemctl status docker -l?

Comment: I pasted the output on github. You can see it now.
https://github.com/thinhduckhoi/ruby/issues/2

Comment: It looks like you may have a wrong parameter in your docker config? Because of this error: INVALIDARGUMENT. Check /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service.d maybe?

Comment: This is the content you need. https://github.com/thinhduckhoi/ruby/issues/3
To be honets, i don't understand about this configuration. I just followed step-by-step of above-mentioned tutorial.

Comment: And the output from /etc/sysconfig/docker, /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage, /etc/sysconfig/docker-network. And check that you don't have anything inside /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service.d

Comment: I'm sure that there was nothing inside of /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service.d
You can see all the ouput here:
https://github.com/thinhduckhoi/ruby/issues

Comment: Btw, did you ever followed that tutorial before?

Comment: Can you comment out DOCKER_CERT_PATH from /etc/sysconfig/docker? And try to restart docker.

Comment: It didn't work. Still the same error "A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.". You didn't read that tutorial but you used to create Kubernetes cluster before?

Comment: It was kind of weird. After the first step which is install kubernetes and etcd, i tried to start the docker with no luck.

Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: The point is when you installing kubernetes which includes docker package. If i install docker the official way, i can start it but then i couldn't install kubernetes anymore because of conflict error. Like this "Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with docker-selinux-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102452/discussion-between-cristi-and-the-one).